# What's a word I can use to describe "putting a collar on a pet" in a comical way?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

I thought of something like "stick a collar on"  but "stick" doesn't satisfy me.  What are my other options?
Anything with some "edge" will do if comical is too hard.

Comment: What's with the downvoting of every question?

Comment: ELU users prefer questions that show that you've put some effort into researching the answers yourself.

Comment: He/she is trying to write something creative and funny.  As an ELU user, I find that interesting.

Comment: Maybe you need to 'decorate' or 'festoon'. 'Rig'.https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=synonyms+festooned&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari.  'Adorn' might be funny. Swathe. Deck. Attire. Dress-up. Garland. Augment. Or go prison-esque with cuff, manacle, shackle, fetter https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=synonyms+hand-cuff&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari or foody with embelish - or garnish? https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=synonym+embelish&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

Comment: As in 'to catch a fish' - landed. Or netted. Hooked. Styled like in hair-style. Dubbed as in 'knighted'. https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=synonym+styled&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari synonyms for 'encase'. 'Shelled'. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/encase. 'Uniformed'

Comment: 'Uniformed' 'swathed' 'swaddled' (as you would wrap a baby, to keep it safe and prevent movement) This includes the action of 'putting it on'. 'Bound'

Answer (score 2):

We can use 'collar' to mean 'to catch/apprehend'. The policeman collared the thief. You can collar your dog, guilty or not.

Answer (score 0):

'Hardening your leash on it'? It is not what you were looking for but it is kind of 'Comical' & 'Edgy'

Comment: Well, it has to describe the act of "putting it on".

Answer (score 0):

You can **slap** a collar onto a pet.  Not sure if that is comical or edgy enough, but it's better than *stick*.  (Then again, it *would* be pretty comical to actually use some kind of adhesive to attach the collar to the poor animal, especially if the collar were stuck somewhere other than the customary place.)

Comment: Slap is pretty good.  Closer but it didn't hit that sweet spot. :-)

Comment: 'I collared him - with his collar' could sound quite funny.

Answer (score 0):

To apply words that mean "capture", you can say:

> ***I lasso'd him with his collar***
>
> ***I cornered him into his collar***
>
> ***I collared the rascal*** (as mentioned by Wayne)